# Debugging AsyncTask - strange behaviour, debug jumping into the code

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-asynctask

I'm debugging an Asynctask that simply downloads a file: here the code:

```
public class AsyncDownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

public AsyncResponse<Boolean> delegate=null;
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    try {   
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        int count;
        String fileName = new String(params[1]);
        URLConnection connessione = url.openConnection();
        connessione.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = connessione.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        long total = 0;

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
        return Boolean.valueOf(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;

    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    delegate.processFinish(result);
}
}
```

I obtain a strange behaviour: when execution arrive to return 
    Boolean.valueOf(true);
it skips to 
    return null;
into the catch block, but Exception e is null, and then debugger goto line 1 of AsyncTask, that is simply
    package com.example.compa.asynctasks;
Then execution goes on (executing onPostExecute method) and, of course, returned result is null

What happens? Why debug jump in this way?

**Task download correctly the file.**

Here code of the Activity that instantiates and calls Async Task

```
package com.example.compa.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import ...

public class CoverActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse<Boolean>{

ImageView coverImg;
Drawable d;
CompassesFileManager cfm;
int coverId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cover);
    coverId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("coverId");
    cfm = new CompassesFileManager(this);

    ImageView coverImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
    d = cfm.getCover(coverId);
    if (d!=null){
        coverImg.setImageDrawable(d);
    } else {
        AsyncDownloadFilesTask task = new AsyncDownloadFilesTask();
        task.delegate = this;
        task.execute(cfm.getCoverURL(coverId), cfm.getCoverFileName(coverId));
    }

}

@Override
public void processFinish(Boolean output) {
    if (output){
        Drawable d = cfm.getCover(coverId);
        coverImg.setImageDrawable(d);
    } else {
        finish();
    }

}
}
```

Stacktrace of error:

```
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.example.compa.asynctasks.AsyncDownloadFilesTask.onPostExecute(AsyncDownloadFilesTask.java:65)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.example.compa.asynctasks.AsyncDownloadFilesTask.onPostExecute(AsyncDownloadFilesTask.java:1)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line:
    02-21 19:37:29.520: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.example.compa.asynctasks.AsyncDownloadFilesTask.onPostExecute(AsyncDownloadFilesTask.java:65)
is the last one of AsyncDownloadFilesTask class, and is a closing bracket, }

Thank you

Comment: some other exception is there doInBackground which is being caught by catch block. r u sure it is coming till return Boolean.valueOf(true)?

Comment: What is in onPostExecute()?

Comment: added onPostExecute().
@Android Killer, that line is highlighted, and the next one is return null ...

Comment: What you might want to do is rebuild the project (if you're using Android Studio, click the "Build" taskbar item, then the "Rebuild Project" option). I've seen sporadic debugger behavior before and think it has something to do with the debugger seeing a different set of code than what you're seeing in the IDE.

Comment: @JustinPollard I deleted gen and bin folder, and then I made a Project --> Clean (in Eclipse), but I got the same....

Comment: Are you sure that the debugger is reaching the return statement? It seems like it must be exiting somewhere else.

Comment: that's the problem! I'm sure that the order of line highlighting is:
order: 
-return Boolean.valueOf(true); 
-return null 
-first line of class ( package com.example.compa.asynctasks; )
Maybe there's a misalignment between code and binaries, but I don't know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment, but it looks like delegate is null in your onPostExecute

```
delegate.processFinish(result); // delegate is null
```

if that's not the case, you're code stub above doesn't define it though.

Comment: Actually, it was null, my stupid mistake.
But I got the same problem, in fact I got problem before than onPostExecute().
Again, I see this order:

-return Boolean.valueOf(true);
-return null
-first line of class ( package com.example.compa.asynctasks; )

Answer (score 0):

I solved on my own.

1st, I move call to the Async Task in the onStart() method, instead of onCreate()

2nd, I made a mistake, in change line

```
ImageView coverImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
```

in

```
coverImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
```

to avoid a stupid null pointer (I already declared coverImg)!

Anyway, I still don't understand debug's behaviour, but I solved my problem.

Thank you everybody